# Recursive code power function

Tags: java, recursion

I have implemented a recursive function for computing `x` to the `y`

```
public static int power(int x, int y){
    if(y>0){
        x = x*x;
        power(x,y-1);
    }
    return x;
}
```

The method should return the value of x^y but it returns the original `x` value squared (x^2) even when `y` is greater than `2`, what am I missing?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "Call by value" ... whatever the next recursion does to x, the previous one won't see it with this code. So this will always return the value of x without any recursion applied.

Comment: @Fildor : And the mutable / Immutable story all over again !!

Comment: @Exception_al Yes :) but slightly different story here.

Answer (score 10):

You aren't returning the recursive result (when you recurse). Change

```
power(x,y-1);
```

to

```
return power(x,y-1);
```

Also your final return should be `1` (since it's the `<= 0` case). Change

```
return x;
```

to

```
return 1;
```

Actually, as pointed out in the comments, your algorithm was a little more flawed then I thought. It should be something like

```
if (y > 0) {
    return x * power(x, y - 1);
}
return 1;
```

If you want to support a larger range of values, then you might make `x` a `long` and `return` a `BigInteger` instead. If we apply a little *math* to the problem, we can also optimize the algorithm. Something like

```
public static BigInteger power(long x, int y) {
    if (y < 0) { // <-- throw an error on negative values for y
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format( //
                "Cannot calculate power(%d, %d).", x, y));
    } else if (y == 0) { // <-- x^0 = 1
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else if (y == 1) { // <-- x^1 = x
        return BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    } else if (y == 2) { // <-- x^2 = x * x
        BigInteger bi = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
        return bi.multiply(bi);
    }
    // x^y = x^(y/2) * x^(y/2)
    final int half = (y / 2);
    if (y == 2 * half) { // <-- handle even y values
        return power(x, half).multiply(power(x, half));
    } else { // <-- handle odd y values
        return power(x, half).multiply(power(x, 1 + half));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still wouldn't give the right answer, though. http://ideone.com/y4yTK8. Looks like it's returning `x^(2^y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me slightly rewrite this to expose one additional flaw (by going more catastrophic):

```
public static int power(int x, int y){
 return y == 0 ? 1 : x * power(x, y-1);
}
```

Imagine this:

```
power(2,-1);
```